# How to parse a simple page using html agility pack?

Tags: c#, .net, parsing, html-agility-pack

I am trying to parse this [page](http://www.bodybuilding.com/exercises/detail/view/name/alternating-floor-press), but there aren't much unique info for me to uniquely identify the sections I want.

Basically I am trying to get the most of the data right to the flash video. So:

```
Alternating Floor Press

Type: Strength
Main Muscle Worked: Chest 
Other Muscles: Abdominals, Shoulders, Triceps 
Equipment: Kettlebells 
Mechanics Type: Compound
Level: Beginner
Sport: No
Force: N/A
```

And also the image links that shows before and after states.

Right now I use this:

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = web.Load ( "http://www.bodybuilding.com/exercises/detail/view/name/alternating-floor-press" );
IEnumerable<HtmlNode> threadLinks = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants ( "a" );

foreach ( var link in threadLinks )
{
    string str = link.InnerHtml;
    Console.WriteLine ( str );
}
```

This gives me a lot of stuff I don't need but also prints what I need. Should I be parsing this printed data by trying to see where my goal data might be inside it?

Comment: Try `HtmlNode threadLinks = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("p").First();` and see if that's all you need.

Comment: Thanks, I just tried it to print it's href atrribute, but gave nothing. Which property of threadLinks should I be printing? If I use InnerHtml I get this: `Muscle Targeted: <span><a href='http://www.bodybuilding.com/exercises/finder/lookup/filter/muscle/id/13/muscle/abdominals'> Abdominals </a></span>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can select the id of the nodes you are interested in:

```
        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = web.Load("http://www.bodybuilding.com/exercises/detail/view/name/alternating-floor-press");
        IEnumerable<HtmlNode> threadLinks = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@id=\"exerciseDetails\"]");

        foreach (var link in threadLinks)
        {
            string str = link.InnerText;
            Console.WriteLine(str);
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Thanks it works. Some of them are printed on 1 line like `name:value`, some of them on 2 lines. Is this normal?

Comment: @JoanVenge, it's the formatting from the page itself. You can remove those.

Comment: Thanks IADF, you are right. I noticed it now. Do you know how to remove it though? You mean line string.Trim()?

Comment: Honestly, I don't know the best way. I think trim would only get the ends though. Maybe a replace with a Regex for all whitespace and replace with one space.

Comment: Thanks np. It's a little strange. I thought they were tabs that were before the string, but seems like spaces.

Comment: Btw replacing two spaces "  " worked. Just gonna parse this output now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For a given `<a>` node, to get the text shown, try `.InnerText`.

Right now you are using the contents of all `<a>` tags within the document. Try narrowing down to only the ones you need. Look for other elements which contain the particular `<a>` tags you are after. For example, do they all sit inside a `<div>` with a certain class?

E.g. if you find the `<a>` tags you are interested in all sit within `<div class="foolinks">` then you can do something like:-

```
IEnumerable<HtmlNode> threadLinks = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("div")
    .First(dn => dn.Attributes["class"] == "foolinks").Descendants("a");
```

--UPDATE--

Given the information in your comment, I would try:-

```
IEnumerable<HtmlNode> threadLinks = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("div")
    .First(dn => dn.Id == "exerciseDetails").Descendants("a");
```

--UPDATE--

If you are having trouble getting it to work, try splitting it up into variable assignments and stepping through the code, inspecting each variable to see if it holds what you expect.

E.g,

```
var divs = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("div");
var div = divs.FirstOrDefault(dn => dn.Id == "exerciseDetails");
if (div == null)
{
    // couldn't find the node - do whatever is appropriate, e.g. throw an exception
}

IEnumerable<HtmlNode> threadLinks = div.Descendants("a");
```

BTW - I'm not sure if the `.Id` property maps to the id attribute of the node as you suggest it does. If not, you could try `dn => dn.Attributes["id"] == "exerciseDetails"` instead.

Comment: Thanks, I did notice they are inside `<div id="exerciseDetails">` but when I used the first line of your example with `.Where ( link => link.Id.StartsWith ( "exerciseDetails" ) );`, I got no HtmlNode.

Comment: Thanks, that link seems to throw `System.InvalidOperationException`.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't do this. You are right, otherwise that single line doing multiple thing immediately throws an exception when I step through it.